# System and Play Store updates doesn't work on Android 4.4.2

Tags: updates, system

I'm using a cloudfone excite 401dx with Android 4.4.2.

System update says "battery too low to install system update, connect charger to continue", but my battery is full. When I use the factory reset, the system update keep saying of my issue (battery too low to install system updates, connect charger to continue).

Still my Play Store won't update because of that issue, and I can't download any of games on my Android.

Comment: What happens if you connect charger?

Comment: Nothing happens to connect charger

Comment: Why nobody   help me?

Comment: @WevanderLarisma Some issues go unanswered. We try not to, but some slip through the net. Lets fix that. So, nothing happens when you connect the charger? (BTW, don't worry about language. If you speak your native tounge, tell us what it is. I'll try to translate it.)

Comment: Similar to the battery issue [on Google Products Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/1gtkSyM-7fw): are you using battery-management related apps? Also, it's.. kind of strange you noticed that Play Store isn't updated (most of us don't realize, since you can still use older Play Store to download apps). Is there any error message when you tried downloading an app?

Comment: @Andrew T.  Since u ask that about battery management yes but without updating system and google play store, i download an 360 security then i saw a battery management and i've been use it but before i uninstall the app i turn off the  battery management..

Comment: @Andrew T. There's no error message that i download.

Comment: @DanB yes nothing happened when i connect it

Comment: @WevanderLarisma It could be a issue with the battery- its not processing charge properly, the chip that monitors it could be bugged, etc. Try another battery, and see how it copes.

Comment: @DanBrown dan, my battery is in proper processing charge. Its in system, not in battery

Comment: Hmmm. I am clueless then.